# Does .NET's HttpWebResponse uncompress automatically GZiped and Deflated responses?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, gzip, deflate

I am trying to do a request that accepts a compressed response

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
```

I wonder if when I add the second line I will have to handle the decompression manually.

Comment: I guess Rick Strahl must be wrong. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: thanks - just trying to understand things, can you tell me if this is correct?
(a) if you do NOT add this "AcceptEncoding" line then
- if you download a non-compressed file => works FINE
- if you download a compressed file => ISSUE (will download file but will look corrupt, as wasn't uncompressed)
(b)  if you DO add this "AcceptEncoding" line then:
- if you download a non-compressed file => still works FINE
- if you download a compressed file => works fine (will be uncompressed)

Is this right?

Comment: @Greg None of the options. The second line isn't about downloading files that maybe already compressed (ie. zip files), but about downloading web resources that may be compressed on-demand (ie. html files). If you do not put the second line, a well behaved web server will not send you compressed files at all. If the web server has the ability to compress files it will do only if you put the second line.

Comment: upvote for the question too :)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I found the answer.

You can change the code to:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

And you will have automatic decompression. No need to change the rest of the code.

Comment: Technically you just need the one line, "AutomaticDecompression". It seems to automatically add "gzip,deflate" to the headers.

Comment: Are there any issues with leaving automatic decompression set even if the response isn't compressed? According to this it's normal for the server not to compress every response: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding

Comment: If you need Brotli support you may consider doing it yourself like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522090/659778).

Answer (score 4):

For .NET Core things are a little more involved. A `GZipStream` is needed as there isn't a property (as of writing) for `AutomaticCompression`  Consider the following `GET` example:

```
var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);

/*
 * Headers
 */
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";

/*
 * Execute
 */
try
{
    using (var resp = await req.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        using (var str = resp.GetResponseStream())
        using (var gsr = new GZipStream(str, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(gsr))

        {
            string s = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();  
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string respStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
            int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

            string errorMsh = $"Request ({url}) failed ({statusCode}) on, with error: {respStr}";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

GZIP and Deflate responses are not automatically handled. See this article for the details: [HttpWebRequest and GZip Http Responses](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/102969.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing this one up with the HttpListener's request & response classes. The standard web request in .Net does indeed handle compressed responses.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to decompress the stream yourself. Here's an article on how to do it:

> http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/102969.aspx

Comment: Good find. Looks like this was added in .NET 2.0. Maybe Strahl when wrote his article he was used to 1.1

Comment: Using HttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression automatically adds the proper request headers and handles the decompression.

Comment: I dont think AutomaticDecompression will add "Accept-Encoding"=gzip, deflate to headers.  I am using .NETCF3.5 and Headers do not have this added unless I add them using request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");