# C# code for downloading item, that checks text/binary, and gzip/non-compressed?

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest, download

QUESTION:  Anyone have some code they could post that will download a file from a URL/Link that will automatically handle:
(a) binary or text based
(b) gzip encoded

BACKGROUND: I've been starting to do this but hitting hurdles.  Like I was using WebClient however it seems it can't handle the gzip bit (need to drop back to HTTPWebRequest).  Also I'm getting a little confused re how to tell if the link/URL (e.g. taken from a HTML page) is really Text or Binary. Is there a well list of all content types that would be TEXT, or the ones that would be BINARY?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps if you could show us the code you have so far? people don't generally like to just write your code for you

Comment: I just answered you on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678547/does-nets-httpwebresponse-uncompress-automatically-gziped-and-deflated-response

Answer (score 1):

You can check for ContentType header in the Response's headers, primarily all text types begin with "text/*" like "text/html", "text/xml" etc etc, however here is a list of content types that can be useful. "application/javascript" etc are also text based but they are in different category.

[Content Types](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/HTMLdocs/Book/Book-3ed/appb/mimetype.html)

Comment: perhaps the easiest way might be to download everything as if it is a binary file, but then check for content-encoding for gzip and uncompress these (i.e. rather than getting what files could be downloaded as a string & which as a binary file, and which are gzip'ed and require decompression and which aren't, just make it simpler)...

Comment: so in fact it's really just the pseudo code I'm after, so how the decision branches would look for a generic file download method.  E.g. how the following checks comes together:
- content-type check: binary OR text
- content-encoding check: uncompressed OR gzip

Answer (score 1):

Does the answer to this question [Does .NET's HttpWebResponse uncompress automatically GZiped and Deflated responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678547/does-nets-httpwebresponse-uncompress-automatically-gziped-and-deflated-response) give you what you want?