# Get the .ASPXAUTH cookie value programmatically

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

Is there a way to get the .ASPXAUTH value programmatically.

Example I login to a website with my own credentials (POST) and then read the response...it does not return the .APSXAUTH in the CookieContainer that I use to track the session.

Anyone has a clue how can I get it and send it with the subsequent gets and posts?

**[EDIT]** Here's what I do to be more specific:

- send a HTTP GET to a page. read values like _VIEWSTATE etc.
- send a HTTP POST to the Login page. It includes the login information.
- The server sends a 302 response (redirect) to some Default page. The forms authentication    cookie is supposed to be included but it's not.

So I was thinking that there might be a better way than this to track session:

```
CookieContainer _cookieJar = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
request.CookieContainer = _cookieJar;
```

Comment: It should be there.  Can you post your code so we can see?

Comment: You were right it was there, I just wasn't reading the response properly. I created another request whereas I should have just read the response with request.GetResponse(). I changed that and boom, there it was...
But now everything is encoded...I cannot see anything in the text of the response.

Comment: the answer to the second question (that everything is encoded) I found on the following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678547/does-nets-httpwebresponse-uncompress-automatically-gziped-and-deflated-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the summarize the answer:

If you're trying to login programatically on a Forms based authentication website trough your own application make sure you follow the steps you take that track the cookies.

First create a initial `GET` request, and then do the subsequential `POST` requests that will do the postback.The request and the responses should be formulated in this way:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
request.CookieContainer = _cookieJar;
HttpWebResponse httpsResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

The `CookieContainer` class handles the cookies as expected.

And if your response is encoded with Gzip just include the following line:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

before you call `request.GetResponse()`

Hope this helps someone out there.