# Read form authentication cookie from asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net

We know that form authentication cookie is encrypted. so how to read the form authentication cookie content from my code behind.

```
if (Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(".ASPXAUTH");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921387/get-the-aspxauth-cookie-value-programatically

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can access the ticket with the Decrypt method provided by FormsAuthentication

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

string cookiePath = ticket.CookiePath;
DateTime expiration = ticket.Expiration;
bool expired = ticket.Expired;
bool isPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent;
DateTime issueDate = ticket.IssueDate;
string name = ticket.Name;
string userData = ticket.UserData;
int version = ticket.Version;
```

Comment: How to extract data from ticket....suppose i create auth cookie like below one way. FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    1,                                     
    username,                              
    DateTime.Now,                          
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),           
    isPersistent,                          
    userData,                               
    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath); so how get the above data from ticket after decrypt ?  plzz guide me.......thanks

Comment: After decrypt, you can access properties directly on the ticket.  This shows the list of properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx .  I updated the answer with an example of accessing the data in the ticket.

Comment: just a typo: ticket.IsPersistant should be ticket.IsPersistent

Comment: Thanks for this.  Also, I believe on last line, version should be int, not string.  But I am using ASP.NET 4.5....

Comment: This is brilliant