# Simple Authorization in MVC3 with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorization

I'm trying to do what should be a simple thing in MVC3.

I've got an application that uses forms authentication to authenticate users with a 3rd party SSO. The SSO, on successful login, posts back to a specific controller action on my application. I then call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user,false);`.

I'm trying to implement some level of authorization. Simply, a user can exist in a number of different roles, e.g. `Admin` and `Developer`. Some controller actions should only be available to certain roles. Details of which roles a user belongs to is obtained by making a call to another external API, which returns a simple JSON response indicating.

In theory, this should be as simple as doing something like this after I set the FormsAuthentication cookie:

```
string[] rolelist = GetRoleListForUserFromAPI(User.Identity.Name);
HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, rolelist);
```

However, I can't call this directly after calling `SetAuthCookie`, because `HttpContext.User` isn't anything meaningful at this point.

I could try setting this on every request, but ever request to my app would mean a roundtrip API call.

The most promising approach I've seen so far is to create a custom Authorization attribute and override `OnAuthorization` to do something like this:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (<some way of checking if roles have already been set for this user, or role cache has timed out>)
    {
        string[] rolelist = GetRoleListForUserFromAPI(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        filterContext.HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity,rolelist);
    }
}
```

I could then use `[MyCustomAuthorization(Roles="Admin")]` in front of controller actions to make the magic happen.

However, I've no idea how to detect whether or not the current `HttpContext.User` object has had its roles set, or whether it was set over a certain time ago and another API trip is needed.

What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought is that you should investigate implementing a custom role provider.  This might be overkill but seems to fit in with the role-based plumbing.

More info from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx).

Comment: This isn't actually a bad approach, although daunting as it might seem at first. It was fairly simple to create a class, inherit from RoleProvider and implement a couple of the methods to call the API to get role information. Some simple caching in the middle and it seems to work rather well. Added bonus is that I can pull into a separate dll and distribute via nuget to all apps that want to authorize against this particular API.

Answer (score 2):

You should override `PostAuthenticateRequest`

```
protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string[] rolelist = GetRoleListForUserFromAPI(User.Identity.Name);
        HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, rolelist);
    }
}
```

It's invoked after forms authentication is finished with it's processing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

**Update**

I had the wrong method signature (just checked in one of my own applications).

Comment: Brb, off to do some testing on this :)

Comment: @jgauffin - this looks interesting, but I'm wondering how this information get's persisted on subsequent requests.

Comment: Looks like it's persistent here, putting `IsAdmin: @User.Identity.IsInRole("Admin")` on the `Master.cshtml` is saying `True` on each page.

Comment: @ek_ny: Authentication is never stored. It's always loaded for each request. You could go about and use the session in PostAuthenticate if you want.

Comment: Yes, my issue with this is that it's being called on every single request, including requests to things like javascript files and images.

Comment: There is now way around that. It's the proper place to put authentication since it has to be done before any authorization. It may seem like a waste of resources but isn't very heavy. You could of course use the session to cache the roles.

Comment: Do you know if the session is specific to a particular app, or if two apps share the same MachineKey, will they also be able to read each other's session

Comment: sorry, don't know. ask a new question =)

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to store the roles in the UserData property of the FormsAuthentcationTicket. This could be done with comma delimited string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.formsauthenticationticket

Then on AuthenticateRequest method, you could pull the ticket back, grab the roles data and assign it to the current user using a generic principal.

Comment: This is a good idea - I could feasibly store a caching timout value, in case I want to refresh the role list more than once during the user session (say, every 5 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Much to the aghast of some, the session object ISNT a bad idea here.
If you use temp data, you already take a hit for the session.

Storing this data in the cookie, well - Forms auth tokens have already been exploited in the POET vulnerability from a year and a half ago, so in that case someone could've simply formed their own cookie with the "admin" string in it using that vulnerability.

You can do this in post authenticate as @jgauffin mentioned.
If the session state isn't available there you can use it then in Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute and check it there.

If you want to check if session state is available in either see my code at:
[How can I handle forms authentication timeout exceptions in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586469/how-can-i-handle-forms-authentication-timeout-exceptions-in-asp-net)

Also whenever using forms auth and sessions, you always want to make sure the timeouts are in sync with each other (again the above code)