# Display message after user inactivity when Forms Auth ticket expires

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms-authentication

I want to display a message to users like below, after 20 mins of inactivity.

```
"You have been logged out, please login again"
```

Specifically, for example, a user logs in, after 20 mins inactivity, s/he clicks any links on the page, s/he will be redirected to the Login page via the built-in FormAuthModule, and the message above will be displayed on the Login page.

**Considerations**

1) It is `forms auth` time out (The `Forms` element), not `session` time out (`SessionState` element)

2) Ideally, I don't want to change the built-in Form Auth's redirection logic, to use JavaScript.

3) `Forms Auth module` only modifies forms auth ticket after half of period. Please find relevant article below:

> "Forms auth tickets aren't actually updated until half of the time
>   goes by. So if you have timeouts set to an hour and send in one
>   request 25 minutes into it, the session is reset to an hour timeout,
>   the forms auth ticket isnt touched and expires in 35 minutes!"

[How can I handle forms authentication timeout exceptions in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586469/how-can-i-handle-forms-authentication-timeout-exceptions-in-asp-net)

**Updates:** 4) session state is not used in the project.

**Problems:**

1) This is a legacy project, I want to minimise changes to existing code.

**My Questions:**

1) I cannot find out an event for Forms auth time out, below is for  authenticating the current request.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/467h1csc%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

2) What options I have to implement this?

Any idea