# Will FormsAuthentication.Decrypt work on an expired value?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

Based on the example from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220843/438615), I was under the impression that if you call `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value)` on a cookie that was expired, the decryption would still work, I would be able to obtain the value `ticket.UserData` (assuming it exists in the cookie), but the value `ticket.Expired` would be true.

I would like to confirm that this is in fact the case.  If not, what happens when you decrypt and expired cookie?  I have tried testing this myself, I have read the docs, but I'd appreciate confirmation from a C# expert just to sure, as I'm new to C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An expired cookie is not sent to the server by the client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vbtchaspnetcookies101anchor4)

> You might also want to specify the cookie's expiration date and time.
>   Cookies are normally written to the user's disk, where they could
>   potentially hang around forever. You can therefore specify a date and
>   time on which the cookie expires. When the user visits your site
>   again, the browser first examines the collection of cookies for your
>   site. If a cookie has expired, the browser does not send that
>   particular cookie to the server with the page request; instead, the
>   expired cookie is deleted.

So if you receive a cookie, it's that it was not expired at the time and `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value)` would work.

Here is some code that shows that the expiration date does not change the ticket data you recover from the cookie:

```
var creationDate = DateTime.Now;
var expirationDate = creationDate.AddSeconds(5);

var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "ticket", creationDate,
    expirationDate, false, "userData");

var cookie = new Cookie("cookie",
    FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
cookie.Expires = expirationDate;

Console.WriteLine("Cookie value: {0}", cookie.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Ticket has expired? {0}", ticket.Expired.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Ticket userData: {0}", ticket.UserData);

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
Console.WriteLine("Cookie and ticket should have expired");

Console.WriteLine("Cookie value: {0}", cookie.Value);

var decryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Ticket has expired? {0}", decryptedTicket.Expired.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Ticket userData: {0}", decryptedTicket.UserData);
```

In closing, if you receive the cookie, it's not expired, and so it should be decryptable