# Uncompressing gzip response from WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Is there a quick way to uncompress gzip response downloaded with WebClient.DownloadString() method? Do you have any suggestions on how to handle gzip responses with WebClient?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the built in [automatic decompression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx) with the `HttpWebRequest` class.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com");
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

To do this with a `WebClient` you have to make your own class derived from `WebClient` and override the `GetWebRequest()` method.

```
public class GZipWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Also see this SO thread: [Does .NET's HttpWebResponse uncompress automatically GZiped and Deflated responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678547/does-nets-httpwebresponse-uncompress-automatically-gziped-and-deflated-response)

Comment: is it not necessary to specify the acceptencoding header for the derived webclient class?