# Downloading an XML file as string in C# keeps getting me gibberish

Tags: c#

So in my C# application I am downloading an XML file as a string, then doing something with it. Some files are downloaded correctly, but for some files I get gibberish. The weird thing is that when I open those files with my browser (Firefox) I get the data as I should, and not the gibberish.

This is my code to download the data:

```
public static string Read(string Address)
{
    return new WebClient().DownloadString(Address);
}
```

And this is an example of a file I get gibberish when downloading: http://thetvdb.com/api/C40F55BF6975A295/series/80379/default/5/16/en.xml

So how can I get the data for these files?

Comment: What do you mean with 'gibberish' ? Post a sample along with what it should be.

Comment: gibberish? how? your code returns same data.

Comment: I ran following code: `WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string st =  wc.DownloadString(@"http://thetvdb.com/api/C40F55BF6975A295/series/80379/default/5/16/en.xml");` and it returned XML as expected

Comment: Strange, for me everything works fine for the file you give: `Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Parse(new WebClient().DownloadString(xml_file_address_here))); // np`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are downloading the gzipped version of the xml file. Firefox decompresses that automatically for you.

Have a look at [Uncompressing gzip response from WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567313/uncompressing-gzip-response-from-webclient) to do the same with WebClient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be an encoding issue. You may want to download the content from the web resource as binary data, and pump it into an XML reader.