# WebClient.DownloadData produces corrupted files from a certain web address

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm using the following code to download an image:

```
Dim strImageURL as string = "http://images.bookworld.com.au/images/bau/97817433/9781743315187/0/0/plain/the-storyteller.jpg"
Dim data As Byte()
Using client As New WebClient()
  data = client.DownloadData(strImageURL)
  'client.DownloadFile(strImageURL, "MyFile.jpg")
End Using
File.WriteAllBytes("\\mappedPath\Images\MyFile2.jpg", data)
```

The code works fine for most cases, but we've come across an image that once saved, is corrupted..

This is the troubling URL:
http://images.bookworld.com.au/images/bau/97817433/9781743315187/0/0/plain/the-storyteller.jpg

I tried using the code above and then the "client.DownloadFile" line thinking that they may have different results, but I keep getting a corrupted file.

I am able to hit the URL and Chrome displays the image fine..  I can save the file to my local machine fine too..  but using the above code, I just get corrupted .jpg files for this particular URL..

I suspect the image is on some kind of image serving service and possibly not sending something quite correctly..  but I'm not sure..

I even tried the same code in C# to see what it would do, but I got the same result..  :-(

If anyone can help sort this out, I'd be very grateful..

Thanks.

Comment: Check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615800/download-image-from-the-site-in-net-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the response headers from the web server for that particular URL reveals `Content-Encoding:gzip`. In other words, it's not returning a jpg, it's returning a gzip. Web browsers are clever enough to automatically decode the zip, but `WebClient` is not. Note that gzip is *not* your standard .zip or "PK zip", so don't try naming the file as a .zip and expect it to unzip.

It's possible to get `WebClient` to automatically decode a gzip response, but requires a few tricks - [Uncompressing gzip response from WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567313/uncompressing-gzip-response-from-webclient)

Comment: That was so simple...  Thanks very much..  I saw that the file was zipped but didn't even think that would be the issue..