# get source of URL didn't work correctly

Tags: java, c#, encoding, webclient, url-encoding

I tried many ways to get source of special URL in Java and C#, for example

I using this code to get source of [this page](http://cdn.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131P&i=48511238766369097&d=20140521):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://cdn.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15131P&i=36224343915714474&d=20150629");
        }
```

but result is meaningless chars:

```
        "謟\bᳰ喜＀緬鋝뜜⎽໼뻥酰曫３䴿㜶娤欞ᩂ䰫힎虫兂⻬쮱ꧪ鈮ⶢ塟⢖슅ㅏ툷杨闌漥쿂ⷑ첿ﰞ≥搁ꬡ뗕㬛⥫꺤ﲪ㸎莜莃␃礒篻譇헃폳繸뛧.牴櫶骶뿟�㟽路鵟癿茶߅἗⺏属Ѽ幟뻞胩쾷霎펳鷕鎧얍ꏉ㺟㤹㶙歺棲発뙯ẚ辌ꭗ﷓㞛輏杖헓쏣쎽귱齷Ნ暮鎋폙뿫收鿌찞蜗煉햽ॢ騽庮䵟弟秛컺࿎콖�ꀲ귕믙殣㴀礸鼲�὿뻄ၷ墊ﳼ擠泺�ㇸｰ充住枦殫濗縭랾鴸岞；毝쟷ꎻ吱⧧릹麜鳝☯퍇�뷴볿ᠺ켃옏翟ﱧ뎃뮧仯柦⭓㙻㤽暺껸嫟쀝ၷ崼鲜�뚹끺鯚住괞澎럠瞿븰븵娾坎陏뜧ᨺ疝㈵嘀뀎ﺺ⦛ꯗ쬞鬘麬ᰟ쾌ퟆൿﰍ擴६烍�㧪᜴缠现꛻㘋㭆栾ꀤퟠ另헬輧懾磲浺廗﫸쳞≐೗굧㩲䵙�ᶵᓧ휻鵯ᷭ�⺝嘏⟋ʲᵛ溬乍□켞䟦컗ﾮ㟦뢦펧᧥쑸飁㔲斾拼쯼껱ⷺ⧫宠쯴嫨ꍰ덫돝엝ꏮ擮念ỏﾌ녮㑸뺟㉲㾙쵟켎韰쏓菭귥菙��忈㗿暔�ꟻ﷧ῷ綼짴즵釲ፕ멪⽫࿎翰㸲䏶ᩐ欼灲墖煠睽稴㼌贗뢹þ綽ɫðꟃ쇡宣❎聋쏾棢㞺�깚鵞뮾乘᦯䚥�뽜泶牶碴᮶뼌瘻Ầ軯��⏞䦍�뛴德ﶂ迆挦뱣鍇捫歗ᯓᮕ焂꓄㞤聆땤灨阮迍佹퍧깄�윂엃뜻暏䝏믖瘎暎ꝧ짳ﷳ얓瓉컧ᵞ컍ཆ뎧䞓ꎣ폩ᳩ寑얋짳귨狉㑶뻝䔉犸䝦㬇騿궜پ㮄쎣๬ﮰ펋㮝ሉ签뉵槜俍✧�⾙ⴞ爐텰鷎꿳뿏利⌗眈⼯蔾鼯⾚붿煸�⟅∈簢Ｘ瑪엾쟅讳뜗⸟��ẟ✯ꌧ퍻⟃類퍦톳ḝ乏䴞틡ˉ鿸�嚄摹挽睴귒少쏎징卙潗篲诇潧엂࿗珁�贔랼鯖짅︊赌쁭ẙ亏߀瘏䟌㎼㱺ᵝ耯瓬뙱᧚汍㡯秘訣킈펗ǩ飦럢㾾籹歺䁶℅㊌ㆪ颗줱݇愄Ҏ㯑͖燇믧맟㬽紹᪲㆙惧磧瑶㴴磵鷧붟�륿ｷﮕ㦯Ꝿ폳짓ৼ盀㝆Ს⤨瀚㽞嬹鯝㸽依⎡๎谞︯ﹲ됅⟍忧籟榑羣㰈ﰾ᳹꺆숿彿䭂ᚚ�箰ﳱ曏Έ蝱䅪睤௼᳨ퟣ奔﨓�樂萋蕾媫＠⻏�쨆縷餶迊Ữ歴⃼人穑뤑瞋ⴟ엝봪�῵៍틏챋㉝⺿鱭ﵸ⦇㙄뮐洐ඦ똺志鲝罍颶튧䧚泾㤵⽊弪ퟱ曏촐菇퇖吒倄砐ż迲撚蟡㶯䊝셱웁ꐦꖦ럒些屡㨆疶햭ꇤ䳭ߦⅳ㓴䷓嵞ힼ餄讇埨㈿엉泙퓾ᵴጀ꛲퇋�杩ꝴ㥥볂ᤡ譝᝿䟗䘏쫮泑끹岳ꇍ醈㝦䷙ਵ澲溏抌�窺芢�᪍ﮡۿ戽돉덧᭱䈥综툗햢ዾ屔૝⠑瓱穾橯㶊풢㇨鲌鎳㻛ꝁ䇯ꙁ趟厠ս뚷綟빬퇾隤뢟߮讈켏﬿﫿퇻Ό쉍Ȃ⾅省뿾쨌�滎飾뼲Ｘᆳ報ꖛ⾚⿧䛷἗籟췴讋䟒킦య秊쨅ㇰ盄෸؊䟌ꠣߓ匃韤幞扼崠㨅醄쵿千拼碱㵬悬躦ゕ惢ဦ些ﮖᜏ諆얫ﻩ氍࿭∝㙪ᰠ㿁辷㲎�攌☷�鎣䏽僓寋䱡鶞䇌웨졃Ｈⷛ濰่猦ԏ쀞ꜭ⡶鿘隯욷澆塞飞뮾㴂웆踟옢骮龯蹄⸴徖䞨풁朗ద谩线⤤�엡ᵪ磕稼쉬䔐阐뷤ㆃ㦤돦夛럂⍔寧䵢썳扮鿃蚚䚶ﻼ쏉펳菿籗糏殸㧅쥘⋏猷畎㩶ẝ�₩�붊䅚鱕ⲁ㛿畨侼�쨖됪ퟖ朲㖳컷붆췈훰汝䖍靓◵㥤籟휋迪獚빨仠獳굹뤿ᄆ㶦⪮수峿�鿌眲떲ﻵȔ梗觝ﾢ﹛⭤㚶ﶆ㝷庶屼抍ꤡ롸墳鮷�겄엱琸健㘝☺㔜윲暭孪Ȗ梼컡褵㛦ű␰ﶩ벰筳瑵ﳧ쾟烿ꗾ⯏곌鈁ྔ㸯綾敳퉖岎蛚즈첞㜯걁똕옹晇稜錗㠺▛뒢樬ꃦ἗帺䩟젢섒䶛뷕뿉䎟뾕शꦒ跆﹯哅緂ꩉ䈢驕摟⃍鴟꯿뫉ㄚﾟ듒찤┪뾝媄᳚ꤱ뼂綄㕾橬젥콉驟ㄤၲ髸霶槪翧㌳몢䗏술습崘ೆ웟䅟඲঵魌㍔妿豯췏䰪ұ뺽悄皓龮Ϙ퉟�㨢Ạ︗ﳤ驿䳹�ꩃౘ皟ﭒؐ톏헜褺�슎獙類姄쳅聭㉨㇩哱훓騭캎溧根濥ᠶ轝蓯ឤ㥴㽶ิﻓ孤樂蔚掽੧짳樔㝊酫끶㡺縿븸氓뫚콌嬇ￎ嚛죥씅ᮂꜬ魇셸잨찍飺浙᪻榶꼥磨齎ᮀ疘ﾟ�⾠돑�ߊ鈆һ沥きͨ뷰鏇ﳹ㇮푌緩筳覰䷆ퟲ⛫〈ᝪꈺ睒멊毴퉕ぅ牔ǩ쁖괒褋贖﫾퇻⟅爍ྴ䙌ᕷ⍽ﱸ烨㜱㴖懘ᑱ尮ﭬ�礈鼸䵁쏮揬䛬暟ޮ뱵쳱﹩ㅰ㈿聫�岵혤ひ럆溗䧇ᵙꦭ❳ᱨ≅䔱쇫⮇홤ﵲ௅앣芁닸芲侴印蔛ᬸ㪓阊�ꮇꪐ䢦↞ཱུ摒⛈䴏㊡먆隩מּራ桡躄讙㨠쐄肆ᅸꆴ텆즄῍禿쳙㊿ㅆ媤ࡲൈૡ㠶뭡뿫旛⿴癇､鯰ㅿ瀹伔㷍辻䙣壨⌨趮䶐᳦췾裆폧糹곱␙˜�㭧6㯙ꏄ㻛䟗⻗>㼭︸ﳹ�蠽䳎뫮윫踱惏鱸澎姞�㿄㏞㼂㼆㟲ڷ蔝㓚⯬轳ﶥዺﶔ鑓喦돒䊝ዶ᭮鶭泟疫�䘺梿⛕藜뛪忏ｿ꬟嚅딛ꗐ뉳噪屖ꏑ괄ꞛ㊔ﱔ㍭剔僊ㅱퟷ뫡ꁭ묚픒ꥆ걮客寳靷뷆擕㬵뾼麜Ἕ㞃궻༚껰䠦⇮ꮴ씨�ȇ专矠�賯�뻟��ӽ䍮寀豠辩䢝铀ꘁ⥏쵅ꤟﰘ�ꖏӿ⁅甌誈ﯔᑣ撊屿�촟ᄎꥂ᧙떂髂삩ᆢ蚮삅鑿獡⢁ᔭ撢Ⰻ諆ႌ㹡╲넑庿謵藹楱鑙ᡢ蕭㓅匈ࣂⰴ奂拃㾘填쐬ℨ뒘鰴☱輱ꁹૄ爏Ḛ㄃ח鸧襇ઈ憐㴨ꂏࡤ�䵇ꑇ쪼⃣켰샃掵訞襴謇螆읱ףּⱹ㫄䊎࢞䧚ຈᐑ⁙⣢∣∵ルᏘ옩坰帣㣰澶㚥눤Ⰰ뜴艄≊漸肈✷﯒㜤긝夑ዛ궩殏췎톎⍖牍懓澴좷䡭罤�⤓喥葄껍費⻛◓㕂ጾ䥳ꐢ옐▢ᆂ✪꼂鯣ओᇜաࡱ䒷鄒ማ뢹葁俭⩈뫨랊偄䙤帄ॷᜢ頣툧࢘氢⑎燶䛚鄚瀅葏እ☢렒䛐齪趐袉饕㱃䒰䎚䍴鄭ꐢ푄풆䓡ￖ넅䦚٢䘣ꈣ䱂栥嶟⍂ᤛ樠䜣薤洢∈醈⊫醲ぁ㓪嫢�呪ꈦ㚥䖪�땑刧䍈議梉趡�籧≳㿳넭伛̰替▸Ⳣ냯騳픑랢쎍뾐�䅕戞龲࢖쵔⢈ₗ崲⭏䈥㌠洡ꎬ놐袖�䢜≙触큠ᷓ阢䞏嵔瓊ዚ楩킁ᥗ᷌≚さ팝蠘ⵤ凖ͤ顈쵳㴺既ꡨ唉슣�铠Ⴢ傌⭇쪠쟍㹉勊᭑䋨嚂宅㝄瀾ᡒ쭧啔刃峛⭞䐈�뵖牔⩳᭦䤌퐻驀ℏጂ⏆粪怰䉜퀛㵥႕즘ઈ뾜敋⇒Ꚙ䉞䢨芠ꊆᔭ䒤좈ஜᕲ㦶뒗㑜兰斦讗院饱稒윩㧅山੒᭍Ç苓▚踮軒ቋ׏굃㋔ꢢ簰륔爘쩜㰹悇셈对訮鐛왝洍蚈棲拠ጂ猒花刟达쩵旅쮍㬮预쌁䉄མዤ⸵咢霒닢။ވԮ⻾尻쒢縅㛈狧蚍ᶉ悉பⰩ㒧苢睬ᜠ熫쪙ꃰ⌗玐稦뢕␘砘⹳㳣装ꉄឫᐣꖪ챧ᙼ⽁偐薢뤡旎䧜봄䘸椼䘯嗱�ٵ鹈☢ꡒ燋틕ᬧ셂˷З밎⸵杢ꆉ钽襆敲Ⅹ혵니쯑Ἤ穤ꯑ닢秳钓蛙連熭읱౴㒸톆炭뢙愡₸㌊ㅈ쒶ݥ䈛즚攛沮놵�ˏ봹㘤਷뵒嗸�鴙臀昋銓襯롋㠥䍯渉㊯�ஜ駛阩⽎丁䙨軎뢪鶈⃴㫢␵ࡨ㛒ᶱ樮点旃邦ఘᅆ◇㌅晫䮲䰙⹹銳얅뢶櫬砆릂ᨃ◆ல숚⥳唳⧠벗⸪ꚻ紁珙ꃁ촬튳쮲舚봆䯀�⪸㬮퇻ւ₽䁰�ᜒ덶὇ᒤ頔輻⌫渣❊뮥찓芴㈙钺걦ﲶꤩ鄫缓駛蹈�ᤒ╳꼊蒙馑涒饮ᴱӈ겇孾쉤좖け킣饭�愒铈銔구铍錣ಞ䗲⻣≛뛓襄ᤃ䱣譭仌䇽�㖩䨡櫔㉳䄛큰䍌훧暙ꫪ泈℄㍁專꫱䛈㙬還᪠૸妦ᆫ啴챬馱䶛㏞桁汋⻮芵玆䮱䆚쿀꾧䶞㘸닒�덢葡ᡨ屜霟掃妰�ꓺ㋒滫氽獴ᬶꡈ집۩⬉鍘畴Σ櫙㹷ꥬ妸莃乮홉竟�泦鐶䚰䠷␔瓏坣䛅鬜㚤앩榜ᖾ瓘웃頴孲뙬㆗냒䩩�鬚Ί䵂狈䱬Ԩ湝氻돂샱陦�璶Ჳꈜ》��侎윪猪꒱워朷놳鮄͆遁땝壭뢲셄뉤겙蛎뮑譑༹�ᳬ틩礱瑥퇘츉磝萠짋瑫Ὤⴵ剘殦㦮擩䝃锐꘼뜳ퟟ殚躎㨺櫙ᝧꭰ㉴疺჆䨟᳇찝㵆꒝ⓘᅢⲝ㷜ⲻ赴ቶ᣸郟ಎᎥ亞劙ᴃ㞱뙁੢ⓖ駐夕⦾ḝંു욝謚笆讦Ъ㨇湩ཎ厠ꣻ��뀑⪋뒄䩴⺢䊝﫹䜖囑举팇佡尗昅ᨇ课㣨㝊᧴᰺雧ひ讝萪琶崠尺⹈璻ぢ讝萪璵ꉚ탸̦騜矌楳苶숣瑪�텃鶴튮佱ꈗॄꇞ蔣ᑭ鈣葵鴺⪋ত剢㆘䎯ᇇ㊹᜺ꁕ㐛婴酬䗎頕ӷऺ泝瑻ꨮ홀猠Ộ�晔Ѧ亞딳㩅唗ന金툭ꢹ�ᴂ密ᕴꋢ⠊켠⋜讝吪璴ꁪ뒫咻�㧻躄㩻탑炠꺇冰᧚۹맚䊨䍥ꕇ匊ꁲ琒ꨮ혰槐�㨓혪淓䱠唗ꍘ⚝ೄ냩䩹綣賐詉␷㨒唗Ⓦ폁쾁颰텚㨕鐴搜ꪭ㙘艴懑ꝏ㨚죉ꞈී㊝뱳텭ꢹ뙢ک�镵ꖫ鹣뜎穴꺋㷂झ쉴㠼㖲棩݃﬩Ꞥൣ愝瑛磩䝃ᛩ앝ᕇ䓒섕蕜꣹摂ꝋ찪ᕇ䓒愕唶赯䟎툕ᕄ！转䟎�ᕄ嵐島礪䊨ꢛ찢궥六䊨꣛崖䟅�ᕄ댉六䊨䭙뚧⫨꨾䤴�뙌坅凱㚅앑쫮䈛텇瓦䟜�ᕄ楉⫪崔鴙⪏覴逪邪퇭꣹魂ʨ岽转䟎蘕㩚뚍ણꉫᒊ婙ꙛ麋ጭ￼䍅榧騶侧綘㨋唟嫂䔴ꭩ痓碞糠鴨⪏뢊㇕烳찑㤦鱗峩ᅔꆴⲃ곉浔캉ᕅꔡ휛툩ꄐ鉡ᶷ脺鴼뮲ഒﰝꥇ㿍폗ཅ꺡尢腔呫먒釴濄䝁鴼ᱻ탟Ⱪ�鴖⪋遒݀뭉宦掣躞蚢䩎㝙�韧ꇝ莡ˉ⼄짐꙽䄮鰧쉿溿݃曃ǧ匤䙗㴧큝憎檒ꑗﭓ崈亂Ｙ椌禭ྸ᠒⊬蔺闐槑鿧鴍�ހ䗑ḏ꘍랳끓ཙ略Դᇋ᫸匛싑ꂈǣ㡨瘝�䇐㋙펡䢬ꏇ⡪झ湴ぬ䩴艁⊦츺㨳㭌᳝ꔏ麣㝎�ꌼ턖랁᫒惝㉣䳿眵㓹䣕䝙㷗䖗ꔏ뷳㔏䱴챁탬ꝥ荴仛㩸葍皤澿亁㩺택膁�鴖⪋퀪搱敜鴀Ꟙ犠鴨⪋伮뙧逡�챁埑톶ᴂ琏鈌☣ꐷ䌓峩腔欉莠䘘䞷ꋧ튊ກᯆ줡㨐蚆ﵬ呜�䳇ཱི㍛䡳䑖탇톕伱锧롇킦宒ả싡䇓슶造襭䗎촕叜䃞⃇鞁䃮⶯䧐읏㝼䳇�娈鎣觹䍖峨텔ڜ쳭鰓읂䧚긢캌ᕅ炭鎠ኚⶲ뜺ႍ᫨⃭橼㖼᜺恕�槐㉈䚷㱇ઝᩴ㒤ᛛ甝鿩쭻ꖧっ瑽䦫艀ᴺ瓳ꆤ㘓謕瓨큊뼾鴌湏뇍鸟䉎躈帠⎠裻艞㡎᰺쳨㻶䞳ꈠ蠣旈ꓨ鴍釔躘◸颂嫛礫❃䈠蓳豁膈峏琦폚蚩䗤鴱맀剧漜ᵶ䝊�덚᜶ᴂ딤䙔䚫朔嶛஁똕༩쎠亞㨆꘨⡣ꟛ◄裨厧Ữ퀳橱Ҟㄖ湝⹌朋೒玠Ց鿆݀㒖ꂇ璶晜틇猐枘籾Ú㓩琏ᩌ㗳恴㔐ꝃ팯ࠑ䘠뾨썉㦤䝧雡李脝輦먝枌伊�䵎꒘䈣컍蛶팎䜧⾇⫣ꨮ佀俳顜჉䋴⎍겺ᇟ米ꗑ鷺⪏႒盟쌐䷀ꑵ抝㔮ᄀꏤ咊鴍洹䎢ྗ陀ꪎ辰刪䂳첧ꮜ䝃䙕왧쮻말ʨ쒱鱥ቌ酆浖腔蟱㻨蒻뢫떽Ꝁ㨛Ꮐ팚蓮獔⟫蟤븡巣擃잏鿶㦘�쬜⩪�眉狮翷먔螡Ẑ␈ᣗ豹䠉౥씋ꖘነ舄撶菜䄔黜㷺޶镺ᰡ轱ꢠগ뤺ᤇ㇏쾆豪糌窉榔댭瞓�悟ƚꇵ墂똌䦏궘䙤壞嬘�伵⇜䇬ꛦ妉૬�呥ସ�桫֎ṁ陣謡⦺ᇡꞬ䤔䞸떘狏祣戚攏먮␅ṻퟒ『杵殑힆鯊�玃៺뱝縻鑥꣤됽룝㶼�㑆呿똾꒮耋䌴ŷழ顐꽴룵�㳫䆩䣴붏騮盫ᘧ㫗障㶍♂炈欄ꫫ�쾜ₗ䞴쏸䦲썴믕ͳ⼐۔ഹ螂C䐓꒰牟ꍳ౰阈捁鸜棴�朠熖捸Άঘ॑寀ᰳ貜婩沂㘀鈇괸랥㡦風畤웰㻄칿䄭㖼짃滀ሂ瀃瀃㮎雞胡쳜葒&Ꭼ㞀㡥뛹話ᦍ곎∕薭昷欸鉖པ챯䙰宬躄ꨁ�ᇻ荙漒烌⬦䤗劃쭯陰銪ᕡ薷⻠㻄邋뱀쌽ꊁ劥ᝨ⩒떅霐농彄䷪踚ꓸ뺩㭮筢朰左ͮ筡⚚髉珹恧菚팺޵扗钙뗕䶧鹢뀂∣婹추譙엶ओ的묉黄셮㶴ㅅ䧯쇾䈼梮⍊ࢺ�ᩍ．ᐫ몢劈�멄ႼᘟЛ꧖ᰶᅷ팬鎗䈮鈩葖ᛓ﵂䵩᝘獂脼⒨灾킑곈狯隙똭ꈘ衚唻ᎎ䂙᝴㮒䂁葝롹鄑�㈒祋䤄訠冥큗鈄蕗ᅵ떐ࢧ䗞⏤Ⴉᥩ䈙ⅈ脪嵤䈚⪢ㄢ䌫⑜≾댣㶺౒挧꒕࡝㦑䬑쥊밑ꂋ䦙搢剂䌨ⅵཹ몕傆ꤨ䌩酒ꋙꝜ卆த锩�曕ꔜ塒∗颳碤ė鋳಴䗑뷤쥂薄馧劄᥉�賩괡浡썲寽婜䚄葝㱦䐭蚷঵ꅐ툐ࡅ骞퍕∮鿯疚蔑ꧾɹᦑ⑂쵕눀》�꫓ꄋꛮ豠겈軪ᐝ᥉ȴǙ䋮爰笯ↈ껁ꧾ齿�ң舼ᅶ욞崮䑸ꮰ㹿馻듨葕⋨唈㏍Ử笡棊ꨑ삋鴨撚셧運ᭆῪ滿䷺カ盶輍ﭬ�缇숽㖛蜼ᓜ嬢袁숖Ⴚ눒�於Ꮓ藈碪蛋ជ⩋㫋필먡꺊萺⇔ິ畡漈℠淑ẞ裴룖㊞ꐯ긵﯍ť몢ゐ엀附�ᾫ⿆棻龡ꎦЮ㱧燐떻刈큅航ᅕ誼唐겄吢ꄕ࡫땖ꬩ铚浕꫊收魕ꪲ奍ꛕ檬噓⦵�垔쩭㚫嗥䶪핹벦ꦵ晭螒⹨邺䄘喂ᑃ⋡畜촑⏤쐮⌜䂚䨄ࡸᅏ䆸靘Ⱃ᥋쉂ᙡ舑ᅶ칍䄟ɘÉ냁❾魶䖉悘ន䔭붚�↬ц䀘썽㣦鰤瑢⦂䛔ڢꋣ뾨퐧Ӂ﫳뱝狅荈퇡檘�憼櫷䓓ํ夣턗䗜墊綼㛃益�⠌瑒측鷞좚舮❄磮䪄棊ᮍն䶺湍ꏗ롟嵅鍄띑鰈倡릳䏐ᝈୂ騐䓔讧縀店ℋዩ�흘ꐢ쫊ऐ쒍⅙脲限舢ﵥ␶䐭킊ѝ陋㞂⁊ȹᅷ뮅騃ⅴ䜼ꓐ鈐Ở쇐ﺬ猦⊡곞捡쮒㬔漈냖ꢗ啔䃙㉬ꁖ൑뛂䜽劅憼㻃騛⛟盰嬍衣흊釗殷췘䠲ႋ끑ႎ곞콡蕾ꄻ�釧쵙귯띨结董潣卶聞碛᮵ࠠோṑ㟢怭�烖꼓齶湁缑ꀏ᫙⮐拣筌鼷瓳�䋟矀㖽滜��飜笄軯｟俩寨ｿ⿦禐⋙柸꠽ਘ［ﳺ诋鷟ㅿＺ㸊瑼�Ʂ἗뺏祹㿾쯌⿔ᴾ뱝尭ᯤ竳㿵籞�ڿ䟨肀废뢼ﹱ�鿹ۍ戂ﱮ㕧⅐⨁잳샘鰚엢䯹︠瑠맾쎭逋诼幯漢໽Ή繾蟾꿳웭䤡쩑䘶뺣菞ꮉợ둘襕챈䋓㚕峿傮彟ꎂ梼�젳檻⥏﨨Ῥ꽏擒惐἗횻괋퉆ࡺꒅ祹�箕潈毁盢術뒨适ႚ⧆൸䏟ꤲ鐀ꔏ礂큎᭧䯼￸駻婵ͧ⿃쪵쎼聄䪞ߵྦ붃륍칿懪않᳦검㊕▤䮔뺲맰ꋯ軚賀鞡䚅鴛�롼嵡ㅞ玞錨愥㡥器삗௣Ϣ삟⽈л聿﹟捴ៜ﹭㕬ṝ鹍ⷿﳬइ찻혼낂�濪썦獸㹷麛㼿鯵蒩ꗘ費닭≝삸ӄԘ�禮鷘뱋쳋�Є᠛睁膥ይ໳䱅芹ট雘┉�ꜣ锡咻橪凞元脁먊茕�戼쳇슣㳘꾵�☜Ӷ젌연誼㳙毴䊞딷�✳飚㋇䯌ꗜ䜶჎๮놹쳶䩆잙覓僂ങ앟෮橳棚ﭾ�狡멶κﴟ挧垌�ㆾ㱻拏ང臐♬᫉葫㭙둵쓡堍뜀⨙셋菔㯜ӞꝤ④�盞澱뗵ᯋ왮䴶톎吼귅룿ԅ훭碮롔竄﵅㈚灱碰ո쩎➥婠戶ᙦ朏晽梼鋅ѝﴣ튊൶蘯솓둦㩰忈頼輗쏧염毜ﶢ陨䗙騑௹痷�싅惉녿㩰忐頬ଗ緧챦픵頦漓೷ퟵꈝ⺚䡟鞑��㯢䤻磊物Ṹߗ댲䭊협珁菙᯷㇑ꮉ⯩ຟ⋭츎疆ܑ뗮ᰋ븱컭ᣐ埞峵蝕ꧯ깻莪헷픾掕힄�㬯쪾ꩧ瑚핟ꨋ籚�먋샂竟�琟련쎙ẓⸯ謨늽᫃싖떆㹸憸᝭꯯樼썾騑漎識䍧똛渓㐆愬ꆾ㾈ꔊ僒嵞樑凮嵞퍳砘ꪟ쬅�殯ᥦ髺軣챡㈳롥㺙薦瑛ꊟꕽ槷�얅䉣梪ᝮ璆㨔�뇑힄쁜絯锊ই醙Ᏺ溸嬓۳誂鲶櫑屽䇶肝蓨듊ᘾโ湟劬䗽閈鉶ᨗꁗ紵匰깗⵫攎봂쿕뗕黸韺间뾨ᕛ閴궘師թ欗敃㳍畘砄ꈵⰾవ㈮忌圯꾈倳송倷佮䲘ᒗ頟䘘뇵Ỹ荽撁뿜䂬욯膙밬�薒䒬슟綹贔᭦㷮誷ុ铜俫呩櫿嬃�膠­ꃟ俚拖䤾㝲痉롓샐寪ံ毣츴쐍᫸譽或鞢뷀ჹ⻳境郇䣕奣꠰됻詓粼栱ﻁ�큫Ƽ븬�͒냨턌뾩ǫ࿮೫㨁蝞剟갷鑃忪韒㖑⿵ᯨ䔯춤꿕顰ꢭ蕺⥸ꏥ슂㾼鑂짌⽵휁篂�穗㖟쪋痪䳖濍攆宝�풡觿㷱曪ӆ嘸玝�⾃弗䶬笼넪螎趗察齺돱㋆䋸ᄤ쇮鄸苹뻔᭤ﬢ彫限䪩롭ණ㮃잮큯ﭱ䐄秉뽘鐳橑�컖ٵ椒롵絳灞暇ꕕ鵐娱ᵓﵛ푠淯햽ꓟ掫䪤뛺慏ᕤ㗪�꨼�綒⩌흯�輁⸪鄟䅤륉拼෵➾ⳳ翖峝垤犁姦꽬ਐ嶥흟ᣮ걮὘ꔕ䧚ﱽ⸲࣊瞊稌ꏬ쬺⠈ꭾ兵핝ᝳ겠䡮穋延篜ꎿ魜軸婇뻻铪彫⯬�뉘ᏽ꒯类损嬕嘷涩췃뭆贙붸Ꮺ쉮稪慱鵒㳎ꬶ셿穻쓯﫹촤�䮉ꮚ⾬죟룙욟閃啀䕵�篼쭇웊�㫌甥콅礒뚏澢벅⺨鄉傼ꭽ켭鯐ⶴ橁뚓�랇ꄭ喬ꤶ਍և瀦깒免쩙懢긫免쩙隢鞝ꕵᣑ�呎ṿ奃빗坞攨뷡隺켪瓻圭�拏꺲㰲ᄏ馡꽘퉪䱌㟴캓肽趉覚䶉覚�睗ꡚ薌㗷䅓譗㒒씊媻䟹捺⤼弖綮挴髭랲갶쩨뢖벯홏Ꚋ퇇斂勒䧸ᣜ詎⾕ښ框퍅죠鋋៊얕틑椔ﷰ䙾潐��᝘篣⿊蟖碮섒儷퓍棥畽❔퇜ᔯ租쬀쾗기麞篛絛퓖몹和퍝냹ួ횶僛¢⢯ɀ謃컠ൽ箬鯰´镇ꘖŁ吾슀�鶶쀗⪺귀갂卢Жၔ㖠琄퀤࣓ꌅ硚⍏趔�잌ニ廅ᐟ죀衉襸Ⲽ郁뉿䯜䪰릌�ⓛ㔦섉Ҝ⒍럶ँ뭮�븡肖伣苀ꕄ֥Ấ襝澚蔈蒽灷撅艍睐艨烷譕ኒት갺偊俬긾ꅫ谌矩㠏瀉쫉≐鯍㭗ꐒ⭦䁳沪胵䮩澥넔꤄᝙頤ɻ䯒챐ካ瞔栤燅튥㷂ᠥ䮮꺰턄↽摄쐡蟁燇�踠ᙣ뉏뒒力ꏽ방ꁧ돋ܰ꯯䥾ポ᫉倶왣曕㍪烳殄쑎ͽ䢫灢菠ᒇ�䡠ɱ䎃尫㦨똁�푋䋖䉞딒敞펫酘镪焸擷脼떢ꤨ킙镱唴땕ҝ酁㫄㨥䄓妬簥샏ࡪ捪抻잊၊䣄艕죊ॗ﷢賹ꖍ䚌⒓弇�䨺ﰻ봆졚ɖ턆ꦨ⠉酝䊐�ᗚ붼K蒽ᖯ㦭አҩ踑猀쉫땸�롋覜�滀ȩ◮ ᭑쳞Ʈᇇ樤딙煙ቷ䠼㕔溗淐樥꡺℠䒼뫕述炓⺃唑य©㷱恃鍚黀篃ꂢẕ褎儇襸詚�ሌ뒵䭉있쉖ꉻ榬䶮ᚎድ촵ᒵ艞褆蜪뗰繲ṥꪧ롊垧ܼ泭⡮かヴꛯ䢭❀烬娐႕鷚ퟎ呈坼қ䖜鎚轚ं釞쾰껚悗艞ቇ丈灠䂎ᜅ䏽伟േ欪읡⮼每蘠쑆煵檪ঝꡄ딬锢ଞຓ쑖օ鵖愛쌘袼஋회책镣଱犥膽랩殰昐ꮗꗖ천讽쏃괹䷫�᝞肔嬙뫍袍ɓ춪쮫䆻ل夑ℕ₴襂뎪ᅸㅟ䮚㱧뤲㰦�砺詯랔᎝⃘羴逡폺厯佴詽念ຳ걘ꬿ戎皚貛䏗桠ᅤ樤ꭃዖ嵅⮛ꯂ값ꄣ합瀫噫┈䚵큨꺤褀Ϊ頢ᵖܛ閥↗繺뺳䝰㖌樂횓ሎϫ十ᴭつ馯욖슕੕蠢栛遐픡텎袡ꎷ殕拄朸튵㡣ꁃ䬀ꀔ暤ᰣᐻ㍝쪳惇뀐唋㗫ᶖꢸᱩ秃婯⢺﯃콊⌫Ր㒰뵨⺾瑝洽鱨젭�঍ꉻ鎁ﷱጆ樢뜪습�賶헐뤵쐸ﰇ㇚欼挊醔牠䙸千胊鸟ۢꆉ긹ퟁ큮⍁홥Ở�㦡㟀蝩략誇ꭚӚ棅氡贉樖ｾ遍鶄眉襟✱ࡃ�ꍌ릈犃腣筞舍䔤억氋逖걥┅惵ӏ㉵쯜㈰ꞜꦑϦ褰皐ꞽ宩໵솪᥸搚啸쐟㶥뛀ᇡ㪨쀻ꓐ혤푇⢃襦퉎膧簂狭乡힢㉣ꌏ檪퐬얍괈뾥袍፯歆⾳ﲍÛ磂∃閵₻툒ဴ಩늅䢍釅⍅뭒Ო䡄别黉ၙ淁哅睵គ睢哜摶鄸惆�㢞ꡈ艆띕䓅⩹⒣䓚첚萶ݵ홒釤綅禁焗낎རɱ糠ჸ定䗻ﭽꔳ뺢洔脸握쎎は胦瑀䭰롼꽰瓂ڣ璦ۃ璦ڣ璦ۓ䒾꺤謰꩏ݱ㝌뀻ᩋꂄ敇믖덉犨箜⚦椭擌軯勔웒鱨ꖀ鐚ힸ쨥윊䡋ک蔅㗣窤칲㖚ꆤ㧉詝魢ⴑ⨺क़렲ⳍຜ㍯枋됛ᖙ퇨ス悽縬䩤㥩跞䐷ꢂЭ╫Ὀ셇䒬銜襙�庆⬶ꈷ嘧莍⯅᪽蟇搈⨶ᱨ槢䋑锥揣鈄⑇⫊ᇇ段늣�涳⠞胰礊柞䐺⟂㘉냴ቁ悪뵕꫆曑겊凞堈镏ﯚ䪬껑諱䵝啽⴪偉뿱뭋ᶖ涺먣透⤮푐朢䋸꽜疛巗䶴ᢂ㛂꯯㸫ꈴ郎ਔయ㳘㪗虧牯푦푧Ɓ䂑颌淚䅚缭๯潆与핮᫞�䝰퉹ഌ㩔谀앥崪睈䊺冑㩏機흱렍亥짃뜍桶淃䯤墎곥咨襏靍䴩촣∛爽�ꓮ깇亁螡솮‛爽漍❈㿝껋휃8쓴ี꼄욻�瀽⼍듛驌犧ޖ猋䖨ᴏꏃ㴦౰ᬏ샴백㕜ᖟ㠌㗋塒䳠ણʂ⫐ὀ도ఊ䞋㮿젢焞⢋ő⟚㖩虨⑆趂㬃켣爈뛶ᣐ茂꫱⾔꒏멲௃⫀ޭ쒪齎恨撙콴癋䴬ᤦ叟㚦啒높笔ఒ㗜퉰恉槖⇀麀젵誘झ�檱윹狀娭’熝싐↕櫒ꐍ䚐딪斀㎈ꤒ⯅主�笅ꡙ餃㵢콯ࠫ咓岝䶾뇘Ṡက晭塝ڵ塍२ș蟝♴᮲ḁ毹熔័㗼僉㹧듑뜆鶑�码㥠駐聥ࡪڭ坍률诗ᅳ䁬஦橔8酖굉횁僛퐆ᲅ췅鍮鄖渑�캯﯈ࡳᇈ盫쵳ꥴ䜙淥缍㫳鮺擉쯫⏪砟�떔∵ꅸၟ鶶橋먤ꈯ梜귥熈ソ㔅ೂш㛓쮝䴻霚룛腶벵砌‶″挡�ᨺ䋄ߞ쏩ꀎ❳嚑蠸䑽⥞컯Ⲁꕮ㾼헣闸쾌嘓韊熙駌Ꟈ鷥⊌禍�꽥돎覱墝�ʜ�봴䁏뜛覇未庚栆簤艿讐Ᏻ㺿征貓鿦啰沥ᕌ́냇틀嶗�怳溽ꌺ輠ꡫ㤧鋦癄焄햛戻〈�ꚳ确숃䴟๽宄裯䦝ਲ਼ռ퉜岌鄌蘋廭⫞햔䠊잛ⳣ揩퀏暴㤛麆聝釻䷝朚퍗㗅郊礁㊝䂢杞ኬ㧐뼣膨蹿⼳羞㲒藹쑾䯜띔埸乛�㔏鞒圎蹚坩ꜘ論拻̯뫬燗ᗒ鋂膦䡄ꓒ萋䴕泺㈇綮騶惮톀㯧怘৵؏㺐쇣炀沎곁툀倹ﬅ瀀同弈옟ϒ䄿嬜溔儅싇꿑版⦬ૃ꺢犓蚸䐕ṝᳺ䓿뷤쮀瞖框哭膫⍆�毋ᓭꉌ祮㰼܉ᜰ蓃烫྘垼甐㡴ﻖն筑鋗氍儁埻̣踭ꚪ刌䘻㗔ನ벢悆豽힨䐅螻ဇ䰹帢뇧ժ잪ᜢ瞯踄ល䭱䁓�ﳻ篂ꅊ鞅帰᥻빠뢛ᕪᑨ䢠웵樻邦벳�厵곐韏郛롱兿갰س蔊먚候ቆ⸅ῃꞘ�¹¬兼᜻㔀⾠唤꠿词Ⴗ鲽̗ᰣꍱ⇮뵣빚☽䚄石㔆㴸࢔㤘僴ꐢ筩᱑⯮ⵉ䥔猼蹲딁ṭ潫»ឨ軬䖔´挨ᴖ✓^↔躋ꭼ੮땈╏έ〛牀⬈₀耋尖鸠ꞁÇ阒ᗦក䫞耫䘤묞退ꀑӜ瞺繲⟐㕎Ꝫ鲔徆鱋ꔰ戬垚쪄䛹¡䟖ˏ㣐ᱫ杖꾈ꘗꈼì礃祎貣鈴瀇䙧퐵멨曋➐�愷᣺ƙ媩쟗ૈ홀ᑶ횵੸졠엀攋濊Μ♈⳩휩Æۚﳾ­Ꮼ機䃏㟀锡⯚딐⃵渎愜賻䇲Ⓓ萁꠺锃㡁Ψ媑쇨譻ᩆ≝옏ᩮ㒃㫢䜿「㙧ԛ駄皍詪댩�燒鲀鳙㵳婛魤懫ꓒ캓ꉗ퉺筵∉뷬麚ꨞ嚤즡撄㦕濪Ⅎ೵Ꭴ똒ℝ฀뮙ꙉ漯ؕꍀ㲣౩䚐與੕炁䁷亹ꇫ쳙늝岌ꕰ农�宊ㆍꢒ显蓇䚡뺬쁵넊퓺⨁眤箻鬣挛�溸腡鞀䷑᫺뷮鞶㣩驮⾢ꎊȯ푛唕栙ʒ鰓緗맳쫳줷衰䢝軚떴鄃ꢀ㮶밽д션뼫ཏ舚Ⅿ노큄瘌ᦑꏜ�鷶㕖ꅭ혖ꇨ㧧慹➣ᑮьㆩ꽴㈈훧⯜覂볏됢宜廫宼≘헝쇇츃⨴ײַ炕�᭵ӈ଻ᝮ믚斗ஷ퐲諌巛듢㣟 Ც笈䣎☣㒝ꤒ畅꓁䲁갲콋椙켤埅弘ꛒ䭮㒈례ꠍᡎვ넷ꏈ摜션码篠磊빧䁷�헤⣩揂ꑩ齙⍧㰊暘Ƀ�竘ᒟɥ�鰐═║ඍ唗壒㢤ൠ뉔䩡냀艘᫅ր倐⯋ථ錉琙蠘餱㶇臆⎩쫎⯯喔㒉꫊㩆ꑥ㉒Ժ縂鑺㣗⧜㌧삠庩렩휔 ߎㅄ☚頼炒T㟺ሡ糺㈄憰㔰䚇禐靾偬ૻ�봆¯浼邏絲渵㧲嶌䝃查쪎ꇦ푛ⵍŌ쓈駦㡛廹﯂䆖嵴㵓⢉㭪碯扩甿䧺ꭦ惧酹誴ᬸ˛ᶉ㘢弼䫓ൌ떖姼涴ⷢ㛊⛳狓ᰛ꫋欴말햼䢾肫ྴ뮺٫﫰鉘丁ҵི콊鎤䤠枢锝堚趡遙綺㦎ӈ鶣㛥Ŕノ璚鍓鄛⨆펑䌹쳶೏蠨�朕ᤥ畴쳁໵뫴䦙䛅䉣㸉亓榙�椠紦Ԍ烂ƒ糮샓顛㜶啧◖ꈽλ화Ꝉ䉋滈ഃ샕癲폘⭖锠倶趖睑郐沰몌蚁ℵ됪癲ఁ䐨ລ὞뵷﫱…願弘ᷟ�巍Ҽ䐸ꚤ얼䦤秏ᤋ骓ᛴ☳㠭�횫忣븢콁í۹퀽鑻዗⋓߂ୀ輲ᨑ藳�ȵ䈠昣࠼裑켙㠘꾑嗬꧞䫱噋ꯊꎉሞ涕়졄쿺舫쾢莏졔ː遱ᤋ⁚勎磚⺟㒀ᘋ緬ʸ膦荖邻덎槜�˞㬚惍ꏩሱ띠鉙탌ꘁ㕙멽昂䓩ݍ鸠惆࠮ࢮ路嬦긑☡ꂖㄍ⨉ᗌᨑ院뛔戢㤬ꎍ᎔ꛮ颂㦦ᇜ䅴姄枠ᅟ㤹௯ଲṀꐚ멸㑍꓋텊橝榡鈶⃘䊦ᥦ⌕˻ᖱ竂Է堦벹䷒溁霭뫗퀩斯濦Ꙥᬩ湿䦜ᑏ㦒䮸쎯鶛ꗂᶊ꟢깴桂ऎ刅虺๝麿ꏐ圔͸髲郭뱐氍谇泍ꐞ⤘뗅舏谌实㈀챰৫䩘߱㪊柦Ẋ➀㪊佶珚Ｎⶠ瘸�ٳ랬蹧홮鰌⥵㆜跡댋ᡔ駑搋賿ɩ囌⮋㬐⿍ૺ熒㉬䎱虂૸⦡⨗傐椠ꄶ⇘若腠뷬㓬⷏錙ီ딳⯋ﺎ䠣ᝢޏ㤇焎홺鲾〧ﲥꤴ捖⎩찕ꄼ軠�ᗸ㨹淘昝ᮞ㦌褅厫┌鸾㒲촌덒劾ꑠ昋渷膙⽬华榙唫諄䳁齡騝惰品⿊頯壘苡ﰉ﫾琂堇᜻柉䪑愓挫ሩ壋捈嶌록몴⸰秥뒰㼇雯⚷痨ﴨ钦鋗�潯误㘟쀓ၥż晸鬅ᖊϼⱌ㲘ᝮ抚셼썰⦤콦ꆎ虭ㄱ畬ᾏﳞ﷟��ﻼἯ紾폼漏簾㟗縿濵븟ﵼ林ᾏ︿￟ﾯﳼﻵ绞࿧﷿ﻺ濛ﶾ�鿛ﰾ﻾ﯼ鼯＾ﻖ�翛墳迩꿽뽟Ͽ᭻媾"
```

how get source of mentioned URL in correct format?

C# or Java, doesn't matter!

Comment: The code can't know the "correct format". You have to tell it what encoding to use. (from quick glance, it looks like Arabic encoding)

Comment: @ShadowWizard and it looks like Korean to me

Comment: @UniKitty no. This is just the raw data, displayed in whatever default encoding the OP got. It is meaningless.

Comment: It depends on the encoding-glasses you view it through

Comment: I try all Encodings in Encoding class C#
but all of them give meaningless result

Comment: Oh its gzipped - it works with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567313/uncompressing-gzip-response-from-webclient