# Unreadable website source

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to use C# to download the source of this website `http://www.dotnetperls.com/net` and do some parsing. I'm using this function:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string website = client.DownloadString("http://www.dotnetperls.com/net");
```

The code I'm getting is unreadable though, here's an excerpt of it:

```
‹     „VoŰ8ý*Ü5Řţ!;q6UlárŰt ×öę ÷7%Ž,n(R%)˙XĂßý†¤ĺH¶€  IĎ{3śyCRYüÂTf÷Â–"YśF ,Y»0ľÔpŔ%Ők.ăÜLŁjG¦3>V»‡\(jcÍ×…}HiöşÖŞ–lT)Ă-W2¶Ş"W¨†
ĐKŞÓę8‡-g¶góŕ<âéGüq”
vŰÂf‘ÇXÝ´°Ű;ŹU
```

I checked the website source in firefox and it seems just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set encoding?

Comment: Try setting automatic decompression of `HttpWebRequest` class as mentioned in [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567408/969278](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4567408/969278)

Comment: As @hellowstone said, it is probably gzip compressed, and the web client doesn't decompress it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You should use web client encoding before calling `DownloadString`:

```
using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
   webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   string s = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.dotnetperls.com/net");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, I'm going to try different encodings and see if those do.

Comment: None of the encodings did the trick, I don't know if it's just me or the website.. Did you try to run this code by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the code before answer your question. you can just set a break point and see `s` in HTML visualizer

Comment: What do you mean by `s` ?

Comment: the variable `string s = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.dotnetperls.com/net");`

Comment: Well, the value of `s` in my HTML visualizer in UTF8 encoding is `�`. Guess there's something very wrong with my pc then, thanks anyways.