# WebClient.DownloadString result is not match with Browser result 2

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient, downloadstring

The following code:

```cs
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string Url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=59266699437480384&c=64";
return wc.DownloadString(Url);
```

code returns:

```
�Q�T�MP�J�A|�^D����~���C�"�����l� ��;I&3=j=�iG�H9Ȓ�J�^� �j��T�Q=HH�'Qm�������1�hF�4�*�������{�x�\o?
```

when I visit that URL in any web browser, I get:

```
12:29:45,A ,3540,3567,3600,3621,3690,3515,140,238204,849582597,1,20140914,122945;;1@2825@3523@3583@1700@1,1@2000@3522@3600@8700@2,1@500@3511@3640@2500@1,;19774,99736,1
```

is there any way to get right string?

also, I use this online Decoder, but I don't get right answer:
[Universal Online Decoder](http://2cyr.com/decode/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linqpad you can run the below code, variation from Webclient.  As you can see from the picture, its due to the Gzip compression which browser automatically handles.
 [image]

```
async void Main()
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=59266699437480384&c=64");
            result.Dump();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not an encoding problem, i think it relates with compression, gzip in this case. Read [Uncompressing gzip response from WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567313/uncompressing-gzip-response-from-webclient).
That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class WC : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri url)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        return request;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var url = "http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfodata.aspx?i=59266699437480384&c=64";
var wc = new WC();
wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var result = wc.DownloadString(url);
```