# exporting Request.InputStream

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xmlhttprequest, streamreader

My code has the following:

```
Dim reader = New XmlTextReader(Request.InputStream)
```

I would like to export the the XML from `Request.InputStream`

I have  log utility which will write to a test file but when i add `Request.InputStream.Length.ToString` to the logs it comes up as `0`

Im pretty sure the 3rd party is passing in XML but i need to prove that its broken in someway. Therefore I need to see whats being passed into the page.

Comment: Use a sniffer like fiddler or wireshark to determine if you actually received data from website.

Comment: Its https traffic, so i cant :(

Comment: That is exactly what the sniffer's capture.

Comment: its encrypted if its https

Comment: https headers cannot be encrypted, but the rest of the message can be encrypted.  You should be able to see the ascii headers with a sniffer. The message portion of the htts is probably zip format and you need to unzip.  But start with using a sniffer.

Comment: would i have to use fiddler on the client or on the server its hosted?

Comment: I usually use it on client.  It will automatically unzip body and in header indicate that it was GZIP.  Your solution may be to use GZIP to unpack body.  See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567313/uncompressing-gzip-response-from-webclient