# Consuming compressed JSON using HttpClient and Jil

Tags: c#, jil

I'm a little confused about how to properly deserialize gziped Json payload from a HttpClient instance.

So far I'm doing the following, but it seems wrong. At least too complicated. Can't I feed a stream to Jil? Can't the HttpClient unzip the stream?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var userEndPoint = new Uri(baseUri, "api/login");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = userEndPoint;
request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
var response = _client.SendAsync(request).Result;

var userGzipByteArray = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
var outStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(userGzipByteArray , CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    gzStream.CopyTo(outStream);
}
var userByteArray =  outStream.ToArray();
var userJson = userByteArray .ConvertToString();
var user = JSON.Deserialize<User>(userJson , Jil.Options.ISO8601PrettyPrintIncludeInherited);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AutomaticDecompression` flag for this. See [Does .NET's HttpWebResponse uncompress automatically GZiped and Deflated responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678547/does-nets-httpwebresponse-uncompress-automatically-gziped-and-deflated-respons)