# HttpClient Response returns scrambled data

Tags: c#, encoding, httpclient, webresponse

I'm trying to get a proper JSON response from this URL using HttpClient. When I view the URL in Chrome the data is properly formatted JSON. When I use the HttpClient, I get a bunch of junk data that looks like bytes or something like that. I can't figure out how to decode it into a string. Please advise.

```
string url = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/calendar/earnings?date=2010-07-30";

string calendar = await DownloadFile(new string[] { url });

private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        public static async Task<string> DownloadFile(string[] args)
        {
            string url = args[0];

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, br");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.ParseAdd("keep-alive");

            string text = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            
            return text;

        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompressing GZip Stream from HTTPClient Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990601/decompressing-gzip-stream-from-httpclient-response)

Answer (score 5):

The data is coming back compressed with gzip. You can have your `HttpClient` automatically decompress this data by enabling this property when instantiating your `HttpClient`:

```
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    });
```

Comment: Depending on the version of .NET/.NET Core, there's also a `DecompressionMethods.All` with a value of `-1`. This may be better suited depending upon the use cases as it will also include `DecompressionMethods.Brotli` in later versions

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove Brotli compression from your request header. Brotli (br) is not decoded out of the box by .Net.

That is, change:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate, br");
```

to

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've provided a solution with full code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77551050/3944285) for decompressing **Gzip**, **Deflate**, **Brotli** or **All** using **AutomaticDecompression**.

NOTE: You don't even have to send a header necessarily.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77551050/3944285