# How can I prevent API returning response as gibberish data instead of JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, microservices

I am using RapidAPI for integration of https://priceline-com-provider.p.rapidapi.com/v1/hotels/search external API with my asp.net micro-service. I need to get a JSON response from the API however it is returning gibberish data. I have tried many things to no success.
[image]

To make sure it is good the request, I used Postman to test and it worked out fine.[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: why do you need to serialize when it is already read as string and your responseValue is string type ?did you tried without calling any kind of serialization ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the response was `Accept-Encoding: deflate/gzip` and therefore I had to insert a `HttpClientHandler` into the `HttpClient` with the correct settings:

```
using (var HttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
})
{

    using (var client = new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler))
    {
    }
}
```

Once I did, the `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` returned deserializable JSON data.

This answer led me to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222690/2504659