httpclient returning data in encoding format
I have following code which return data from httpclient, but it looks like it's not giving data in proper json format.
Below is code and response.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 2147483647;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

var response = await client.GetAsync("URL");
Var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Data is coming it looks like this:
`"\u001f�\b\0�аf\0\u0003���r\u001bW���WA�Z�s�<�/:H��e\u001dMA���\u000e\aD�\"J$ ����\u0015�J�\u0010�d�\0A2OT\u0002Ā�s���e\u0013,p\u0010@~\u001aY����\u007f\u001f|>\u001b�=\u001e}y��A?�����xv2z�\u007f0�q��˫��ޯ\u000f\u001e>8\u001a�\u001f��?���I�P�\vOO\u001fv\u001eMO����:\u007f�g�OL���x<\u001bu��'G��䨳\u007f6��\u0019\f'�������_\u0017��\v���Ë�N��㏓�Q�p4���\u001evf��Igt�qt��$���.����� L�0M���N�C�y�����Ő�G���\u001c��O�f���\u001ff���0�F\u0013Ea�[��������\a�\u0017gg����Gӣ�3�<~p��6��>�|��7��?{{�E��yYc��خ\u0003��ͰfϘwu�l:����w��\u001c\u001e�c�tS���TiM�$�i\\s)�]/��x~)ش�{��X�˳4S���L�q&�KM���*�.g�\u001bg�{��o..."


HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression Property

@AlexanderPetrov I have already set client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222690/5045688

@AlexanderPetrov you saved my day.. it's working.. Many thanks...
